# Adding Django-admin-action with conditions

Tags: python, django, django-admin-actions

I have my django model `Customer` which consists of these fields;

*'Customer_ID', 'Name', 'Gender',* 'Age'*, 'Nationality', 'Address',* 'Account_Type'*,* 'Salary'*,* 'Balance'*,* 'Employer_Stability'*,* 'Customer_Loyalty'*,* 'Residential_Status' *and **'Service_Level'***

where `Service_Level` = `Silver`, `Gold` or `Platinum`.

I have managed to create a custom-admin-action to just update the Service_Level without any condition as shown below;

```
def allocate_service(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(Service_Level=2)

@admin.register(models.Customer)
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    icon = '<i class="material-icons">account_box</i>'
    list_display = ('Customer_ID', 'Name', 'Gender', 'Nationality', 
                'Account_Type', 'Salary', 'Balance', 'Service_Level')
    list_per_page = 10
    list_filter = ('Nationality', 'Gender')
    actions = [allocate_service ]
```

I would like to add an action that assigns the Service_Level to a customer/ customers depending on the values of the bold features above (Age, Salary etc.).
e.g. 
when `Age > 25 and Salary >= 800 and Account_Type == Savings` then `Service_Level = Platinum`.

my Models are as follows:

```
class Service(models.Model):
#service_no = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=4)
service_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
service_description = models.TextField(default='')

class Meta:
    db_table = 'services'
    ordering = ['service_name']

def __str__(self):
    return self.service_name

# Customer Model: too big so I ommited the other fields here

class Customer(models.Model):
    Service_Level = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        db_column='service_name', null=True, blank=True)
```

I removed the option to use int key on Service_Level

I am not sure how I am supposed to go about it. Help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you looked at the official [django admin actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/actions/)?

Comment: @nik_m I am able to create custom actions, for example; I created an action to export to CSV and another one to update the ***Service_Level*** without a condition. 

 `def allocate_service(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(Service_Level=2)`
this updates the Service_Level column to Silver. However, I am failing to implement conditions as mentioned above

Comment: You must update your question with more details. What do you want to happen when you select one or more customers? You have to be more specific!

Comment: thanks @nik_m, I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the queryset and perform your conditions on each one seperately, instead of just applying a "global" `update` to all (`queryset.update(Service_Level=2)`).

```
from django.contrib.messages import SUCCESS

def allocate_service(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    platinum_customers = []
    silver_customers = []
    message = ''

    for customer in queryset:
        if customer.Age > 25 and customer.Salary >= 800 and customer.Account_Type == 'Savings':
            customer.Service_Level.service_name = 'Platinum'
            platinum_customers.append(customer.name)
        elif other_condition_here:
            customer.Service_Level.service_name = 'Silver'
            silver_customers.append(customer.name)
        customer.save()

    if platinum_customers:
        message = 'The following customers are now platinum: {}'.format(', '.join(platinum_customers))
    if silver_customers:
        message = 'The following customers are now silver: {}'.format(', '.join(silver_customers))
    if not platinum_customers and not silver_customers:
        message = 'No customer changes!'
    modeladmin.message_user(request, message, level=SUCESS)
```

Comment: It is not updating the table field. it is just returning a null

Comment: It is now just displaying a message with customer name but not adding the Service_Level. see image http://imgur.com/a/x1LjF

Comment: Show your models please. Maybe the lines `customer.Service_Level == 'Platinum'` and `customer.Service_Level == 'Silver'` might become `customer.Service_Level == 1` and `customer.Service_Level == 2`, respectively.

Comment: I added the models on the question

Comment: I thought I did not have to include the other object since they are related. I am now getting an error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'service_name'`

Comment: That's very weird.... Put a `print(customer.Service_Level)` after the `for` loop and comment out all the rest. Now, select multiple customers and execute this action. Does it print the `Service_Level` names? If yes, then change to `print(customer.Service_Level.service_name)` and perform same steps.

Comment: `print(customer.Service_Level` is printing `None` and the other one is returning the `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'service_name'`

Comment: I think I had a typo in my code. I had `customer.Service_Level.service_name == 'Platinum'` instead of `customer.Service_Level.service_name = 'Platinum'`. Note the double `=`.

Comment: yeah that helped too but it gave a `Cannot assign "'Platinum Package'": "Customer.Service_Level" must be a "Service" instance.` so I ended up editing my assignment to

`customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = 'Silver Package')` and it added the Service_Level.